# Using Nuxt 3 cookies in tailwind.confg file

Tags: cookies, vuejs3, tailwind-css, nuxtjs3

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have a variable that a user can update to change the primary color of the app. I can't figure out how to get the `tailwind.confg.js` file to communicate with my Nuxt app so it know what to set the primary color to. I've been trying to do this with cookies using different cookie libraries, but every time the `tailwind.config.js` file shows that the cookie is `undefined` and the browser shows the correct value.

I have tried settings cookies using the build in Nuxt's `useCookie`, using VueUse's `useCookies` and using `universal-cookies` and haven't been able to figure it out. I cannot get the cookie to show up correctly in the `tailwind.config.js` file. Here are my configs and a copy to my stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-qinx8e?file=app.vue

app.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="bg-red-600 h-16 mb-4">HELLO WORLD</div>
    <div class="bg-primary-600 h-16 mb-4">HELLO WORLD</div>
    <button class="bg-blue-200 rounded-lg p-4 mx-2" @click="myColor = 'blue'">
      Blue
    </button>
    <button class="bg-green-200 rounded-lg p-4" @click="myColor = 'green'">
      Green
    </button>
    <body class="mx-2">
      My color is: {{ myColor }}
    </body>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const myColor = useCookie('myColor', {
  default: () => 'orange',
  watch: true,
});
</script>
```

tailwind.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');
// need to figure out how to make this dynamic
const color = 'blue';

exports.darkMode = 'class';
exports.content = [
  './components/**/*.{js,vue,ts}',
  './layouts/**/*.vue',
  './pages/**/*.vue',
  './plugins/**/*.{js,ts}',
  './nuxt.config.{js,ts}',
  './app.vue',
];

if (color === 'blue') {
  exports.theme = {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: colors.blue,
      },
    },
  };
}
if (color === 'green') {
  exports.theme = {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: colors.green,
      },
    },
  };
}
if (color === 'orange') {
  exports.theme = {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: colors.orange,
      },
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to achieve this as Tailwind compiles classes during runtime. And even if you do every user who change color will change utility properties for every other user. Use CSS variables and store them instead

Comment: Thank you @IharAliakseyenka I was thinking about this all wrong. It will take a bit more work but makes sense to have the logic for changing colors in the vue components where it will only be rendered on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Ihar answered the question, I was thinking about things all wrong and not realizing this would change for the server side, not just the client. I will do my logic in the Vue components to change color just for the client.

Comment: looks as if this is a comment to an answer instead of an answer